# How do I rotate a pgm file clockwise?

Tags: c++, pgm

I have tried many things and can't get it right. I know that the first row = the last column, but don't know how to swap the two.

```
void pgm_cw(vector<IVec>& p) {
  int rows = p.size();
  int cols = p[0].size();
  vector<IVec> temp;  //2nd vector to hold rotated
  temp.resize(cols);
  for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      temp[i].resize(rows);
  }

}
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what `IVec` means. I guess it's `std::vector<uint8_t>` but not sure.

Comment: Ya my bad. IVec is a vector of ints.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a diagram on paper: draw a point inside a rectangle, call its coordinates e.g. `x,y` and try to "guess" or "estimate" which coordinates it has in the rotated rectangle. Remember that coordinates start at 0. I believe it's `y,cols-x-1`, but check it for yourself.

Then do nested loop, copying pixel values to the corresponding coordinates.

```
size_t image1_x_limit = image1[0].size();
size_t image1_y_limit = image1.size();
for (size_t image1_y = 0; image1_y < image1_y_limit; ++image1_y)
{
    for (size_t image1_x = 0; image1_x < image1_x_limit; ++image1_x)
    {
        size_t image2_x = image1_y_limit - 1 - image1_y;
        size_t image2_y = image1_x;
        image2[image2_y][image2_x] = image1[image1_y][image1_x];
    }
}
```

Comment: for counter clockwise would i just change the image2_x = image1_y? EDIT: i figured it out. thanks for the help!